# Calculating timespan in C

Tags: c, timer, timespan

I'll be brief:

I want to measure the timespan in C for such small thing as this send in sockets:

```
sendto (s, buffer, sizeof (buffer), 0, (struct sockaddr *) &peer, peerlen);
```

I'm currently doing this:

```
clock_t cBegin = (double)clock () * CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
sendto (s, buffer, sizeof (buffer), 0, (struct sockaddr *) &peer, peerlen);
clock_t cEnd = (double) clock() * CLOCKS_PER_SEC;

elapTicks = cEnd - cBegin;
elapMilli = elapTicks/1000;

printf ("Milisegundos: %lf, %lf\n", cBegin, cEnd);
```

But my printf are always 0.000000. How should I proceed?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: One of your problems is that you should *divide* by `CLOCKS_PER_SEC`, not multiply.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On POSIX-ish systems, use `gettimeofday()` or `clock_gettime()` instead.

The `clock()` function only tells you how much CPU time has been used.   If your code spends most of its time sleeping, waiting for something to happen, it will use very little CPU.

However, `sendto()` only passes your datagram to the networking layer.   It does not wait for the remote system to receive it.   If you want to time how long it takes, you will need to wait for a reply.   If that is not what you had in mind, another alternative is to make a loop, and time how long it takes to issue many `sendto()` calls.   However, this will very likely give results that are confounded with the effect of passing megabytes of data into the networking stack (which, in the case of UDP, will not coalesce successive writes).

Comment: Thank you very much. And even more for the comments regarding the sendto operation. Regarding to the clock function, I should just change it for clock_gettime()?

Comment: @PedroDusso Yes, to perform elapsed-time measurements, use `clock_gettime()` if your system has it (i.e. if it is a POSIX-like system).